# Error trying to complie function due to function C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

Do I keep getting this error when I'm trying to compile this function I can't figure out what to do?

> [brgod@lisa pa06]$ g++ -std=c++11 -o letters letters.cpp 
>   /tmp/ccyzLa31.o: In function main':
>
> letters.cpp:(.text+0x21e)
>
> undefined reference to `search(int*, int, int)`' collect2: error: ld
>   returned 1 exit status

```
#include <iostream> //(Normally formatted correctly running into error when posting
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream> 
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm> 

void search(int ab[], int number_used, int target);
using namespace std;
stringstream ss;
int main()
{
    int a=97;
    int b=98;
    int c=99;
    int d=100;
    int e=101;
    int f=102;
    int g=103;
    int h=104;
    int i=105;
    int j=106;
    int k=107;
    int l=108;
    int m=109;
    int n=110;
    int o=111;
    int p=112;
    int q=113;
    int r=114;
    int s=115;   
    int t=116;
    int u=117;
    int v=118;
    int w=119;
    int x=120;
    int y=121;
    int z=122;
    char number_1[432];
    cout << "Enter text:\n";
    cin >> number_1;
    long xb;
    xb=strlen(number_1);
    long ci=0;
    int bruh[xb];
    for (long bi=0; bi<xb; bi++)
    {
        bruh[bi]=number_1[bi];
    }
    sort(bruh, bruh+xb);
    search(bruh,xb,a);
}

void search(const int ab[], int number_used, int target)
{
    int a=97;
    int b=98;
    int c=99;
    int d=100;
    int e=101;
    int f=102;
    int g=103;
    int h=104;
    int i=105;
    int j=106;
    int k=107;
    int l=108;
    int m=109;
    int n=110;
    int o=111;
    int p=112;
    int q=113;
    int r=114;
    int s=115;
    int t=116;
    int u=117;
    int v=118;
    int w=119;
    int x=120;
    int y=121;
    int z=122;
    int index=0;
    int count=0;
    bool found=false;
    while ((!found) && (index < number_used))
    {   
        if(target==ab[index])
        {
            found=true;
            count++;
            index++;
        }
        else
        {
        index++;
        }
    }
    if (count>0)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried editing your code, but it is way too messy. Please edit your question and copy-paste the code directly from you editor, as plain text, then indent it via the `{}` button.

Answer (score 2):

The first parameter of your function `search` is not `const` in your pre-declaration against your function definition.

Comment: for some reason haven't seen your answer and posted mine which basically repeated yours (now deleted), +1